# NotImplementedError: Method 'HardhatEthersProvider.resolveName' is not implemented

Tags: hardhat, test

I'm trying to implement meta transactions for my web app. I'm currently testing the smart contracts using hardhat but keep running into this error in my `NodeManager.ts` file. The error below

```
 1) NodeManager Contract
       Should create a node and transfer tokens:
     NotImplementedError: Method 'HardhatEthersProvider.resolveName' is not implemented
      at HardhatEthersProvider.resolveName (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.ts:355:11)
      at HardhatEthersSigner.resolveName (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:108:26)
      at resolveAddress (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\address\checks.ts:113:46)
      at C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:172:60
      at ParamType.#walkAsync (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments.ts:776:24)
      at ParamType.walkAsync (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments.ts:794:24)
      at C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:170:22
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at resolveArgs (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:169:37)
      at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (C:\Users\Jexarx\React\Final Year Project\backend\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\factory.ts:90:47)
```

The code

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import Security from "../helpers/functions";

const {
  loadFixture,
} = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox/network-helpers");


const { expect } = require("chai");
const { vars } = require("hardhat/config");

describe("NodeManager Contract", function () {

  async function deployNodeFixture() {
    const security = new Security();
    const [owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const traceCredit = await ethers.deployContract("Credit");
    await traceCredit.waitForDeployment();

    // environment vars set with https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/configuration-variables
    const ADMIN_ENCRYPTED_ADDRESS = vars.get("ADMIN_ENCRYPTED_ADDRESS");
    const trustedForwarder = security.decrypt(ADMIN_ENCRYPTED_ADDRESS); 

    const traceCreditAddress = await traceCredit.getContractAddress();
    const nodeManager = await ethers.deployContract("NodeManager", [traceCreditAddress, trustedForwarder]);
    await nodeManager.waitForDeployment();

    // creates the variables to be used in different tests to avoid duplication
    return { nodeManager, owner, addr1, addr2 };
  }

  it("Should create a node and transfer tokens", async function () {
    const { nodeManager, addr1, addr2 } = await loadFixture(deployNodeFixture);
    await nodeManager.transfer(nodeManager.address, 100);

    await nodeManager.connect(addr1).createNode(addr2.address, 50, 1);

    const [sender, receiver, amount, postId] = await nodeManager.getNodeDetails(0);
    expect(sender).to.equal(addr1.address);
    expect(receiver).to.equal(addr2.address);
    expect(amount).to.equal(50);
    expect(postId).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

When I try and construct the `nodeManager`, the traceCredit address seems to be causing the problem. I've logged both the constructor parameters and they've returned hex addresses which seem correct.

The smart contract in question
Credit.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Credit is ERC20 {
  address public owner;

  constructor() ERC20("Trace Credit", "TC") {
    _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10**decimals());
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint");
    _mint(account, amount);
  }

    // getter for address of smart contract
  function getContractAddress() external view returns (address) {
    return address(this);
  }

  function burn(uint256 amount) external {
    _burn(msg.sender, amount);
  }
}
```

NodeManager.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "./Credit.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Context.sol";

contract NodeManager is ERC2771Context {
  struct Node {
    address sender;
    address receiver;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 postId;
  }

  Credit public creditToken;

  mapping(uint256 => Node) public nodes;
  uint256 public nodesCount;

  constructor(address creditTokenAddress, address trustedForwarder) ERC2771Context(trustedForwarder) {
    creditToken = Credit(creditTokenAddress);
  }

  function createNode(address receiver, uint256 amount, uint256 postId) external {
    // Use the _msgSender() from ERC2771Context to get the actual sender of the meta transaction
    creditToken.transferFrom(_msgSender(), receiver, amount);

    // Add to the chain
    Node storage newNode = nodes[nodesCount];
    newNode.sender = _msgSender();
    newNode.receiver = receiver;
    newNode.amount = amount;
    newNode.postId = postId;

    nodesCount++;
  }

  function getNodeDetails(uint256 nodeId) external view returns (address, address, uint256, uint256) {
    console.log("HERE");
    require(nodeId < nodesCount, "Invalid node ID");
    Node storage node = nodes[nodeId];
    return (node.sender, node.receiver, node.amount, node.postId);
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding more logs. It is likely one of the address is undefined or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the `address trustedForwarder` parameter was the problem. I changed it for a relayer in openZeppelin and it fixed the problem

Comment: Always good to provide more context for readers why changing it to relayer resolves the problem.